# How to make Firefox Quantum use Windows notifications

Tags: windows-10, firefox, notifications

I use the Pushbullet addon for Firefox, which displays my phone's notifications on my computer using the Firefox native notifications API. (I don't really know what it is officially called)

[image: Example Pushbullet Notification on Firefox]

I would really like to somehow make Firefox use the Windows notification API through the notification center. The Pushbullet app for Windows does this, but it has been behaving weirdly lately and I decided to not use it anymore.

Is there any way to do this in Firefox Quantum?

Comment: If you're not using Pushbullet anymore....how are the notifications getting from your phone to Firefox?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I'm not using the Pushbullet app for Windows anymore, I still use the Android app.